# Nullable date in avro schema for google pub/sub

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I'm using avro as the schema for google pub/sub to write directly to BigQuery.

One of the fields can be null, so I've written my avro schema like this:

```js
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "status",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "createDate",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "purchaseDate",
      "type": ["null", "string"]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, for an input to fit with this schema, it has to look something like one of the below:

```js
{
  "id": "123",
  "status": "not-purchased",
  "createDate": "2023-01-17T04:49:16.966Z",
  "purchaseDate": null
}
```

```js
{
  "id": "123",
  "status": "purchased",
  "createDate": "2023-01-17T04:49:16.966Z",
  "purchaseDate":  {
    "string": "2023-01-17T04:49:16.966Z"
  }
}
```

The input in the 2nd example above is not in a format that is expected by the BigQuery subscription. I'm looking for something that looks like this instead:

```js
{
  "id": "123",
  "status": "purchased",
  "createDate": "2023-01-17T04:49:16.966Z",
  "purchaseDate": "2023-01-17T04:49:16.966Z"
}
```

Is there something I did wrong with the avro schema or is it just the way it is for how nullable fields works in avro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: This issue has now been fixed.

**Original answer**: This is a known issue with Pub/Sub BigQuery subscriptions. You can follow the progress on a fix in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242757468). Once fixed, the example that uses the `string` keyword should work for inserting into BigQuery via Pub/Sub subscription.

Comment: Thank you for linking that, glad to see fixes are being worked on.
I've since decided to use protocol buffer (protobuf), and there's no longer such limitation. Making a field optional is very easy there with just the optional keyword.

Comment: The linked issue seems to say the data still needs the string key, but it's not written. This isn't exactly what OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable doesn't matter. It's just a union type.

The string key is required for union types, as per the Avro JSON encoding specification.

Comment: thank you for confirming that, think I'll either have to resort to handling null values in other ways, or look into protocol buffer instead